# Evaluate $f(x,y,z) = z^3$ on the region defined by $z \geq 0 \ x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \ x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, multiple-integral

I am asked to solve the following problem:

> Changing the variables, evaluate the integral of the function
>   $f(x,y,z) = z^3$ on the region defined by $z \geq 0 \quad x^2+y^2 \leq
>  1 \quad x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2$.

I thought about using spherical coordinates:

$$
0 \leq \rho \leq \sqrt{2}\\
0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi\\
0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

with $\rho^5cos^3(\phi)sin(\phi)$ on the integral, but that didn't work.

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} \rho^5cos^3(\phi)sin(\phi) \ d\rho d\theta d\phi
$$

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stay within the cylinder, the sphere is only the 'cap' (on top) so you can't have constant (outer) limits for $\phi$ and $\rho$.

I think cylindrical coordinates are more appropriate than spherical ones. In cylindrical coordinates you simply have $r:0\to1$ and $t:0 \to 2\pi$ and for the top, $z : 0 \to\sqrt{2-r^2}$ since:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2 \Leftrightarrow z^2 = 2-(x^2+y^2) = 2- r^2$$
The integral then becomes:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{2-r^2}} z^3 r \,\mbox{d}z \,\mbox{d}r \,\mbox{d}t = \cdots = \frac{7\pi}{12}$$
The calculations are a lot easier than doing it straight in Cartesian coordinates:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}} z^3 \,\mbox{d}z \,\mbox{d}y \,\mbox{d}x = \cdots = \frac{7\pi}{12}$$

Comment: You're welcome!